# Follow up Question for TKinter ComboBox Variable Issue - adding button functionality

Tags: python, tkinter, button, combobox

I recently asked and had answered this questions here for reference:
[TKinter ComboBox Variable Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72567680/tkinter-combobox-variable-issue/72568110#72568110)

I am now adding a button and function to display a choice selected. I believe the issue is something to do with this being a dictionary and not a list. Here is a snipit of my Class I have so far:

```
                    # ---------------- HP Pool Option --------------#
    hp_pool_options = {"Low" : (
                    "5","10","15","20",
                    "25","30","35","40",
                    "45","50","55","60",
                    "65","70","75","80",
                    "85","90","95","100"),

                "Medium" : (
                    "105","110","115","120",
                    "125","130","135","140",
                    "145","150","155","160",
                    "165","170","175","180",
                    "185","190","195","200",),

                "High" : (
                    "205","210","215","220",
                    "225","230","235","240",
                    "245","250","255","260",
                    "265","270","275","280",
                    "285","290","295","300",),

                "Extreme" : (
                    "325","350","375","400",
                    "425","450","475","500",
                    "525","550","575","600",
                    "625","650","675","700",
                    "725","750","775","800",)}
    
    def on_pool_selected(hp_value):
        hp_values = ('Random',)
        if hp_value == 'Random':
            for v in hp_pool_options.values():
                hp_values += v
        else:
            hp_values += hp_pool_options[hp_value]
        hp_value_combobox.configure(values=hp_values)
        hp_value_combobox.set('Random')
        
    
    #Label
    hp_pool_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_left, text="HP Option")
    hp_pool_label.grid(row=5,column=0)
    hp_var1 = customtkinter.StringVar()
    hp_pool_combobox = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=self.frame_left, 
                                    variable=hp_var1, 
                                    values=("Random",)+tuple(hp_pool_options.keys()), 
                                    command=on_pool_selected)
    hp_pool_combobox.grid(row=5, column=1)
    

    hp_var2 = customtkinter.StringVar()
    hp_value_combobox = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=self.frame_left, variable=hp_var2)
    hp_value_combobox.grid(row=5, column=2)
    hp_value_combobox.set("Random")
    hp_pool_combobox.set("Random")
    
    #TODO
    #Add HP Value function
    def add_hp_value():
        hp_value_choice = StringVar()
        hp_value_choice = hp_value_combobox.get()
        random_hp_value = random.choice(hp_values)
        if hp_value_choice == "Random":
            display_hp_value['text'] = random_hp_value
        else:
            display_hp_value['text'] = hp_value_choice
    #Display HP Value
    display_hp_value = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_right, text='')
    display_hp_value.grid(row=5,column=1)
    #Create button to add HP Value
    add_hp_value_btn = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.frame_left, text="Add HP Value", command=add_hp_value()) 
    add_hp_value_btn.grid(row=5, column=3)
```

The issue I am seeing is in the button function. random_hp_value is trying to pull from hp_values but is out of the scope. How can I return those hp_values into a list variable to then put into my button function?

Comment: I am not exactly sure where you issue lies, but the way you set ```hp_value_choice ``` seems like a source for problems. You first set it as a ```StringVar``` then you set it to a value. To set the value you should use ```hp_value_choice.set(value=hp_value_combobox.get())``` or simply combine the two lines with ```hp_value_choice = StringVar(value=hp_value_combobox.get())```

Comment: You can use `hp_value_combobox.values` to get the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute `values` of `hp_value_combobox` to get the values of the combobox. To exclude the `Random` value, use `hp_value_combox.values[1:]`.

```py
def add_hp_value():
    ...
    random_hp_value = random.choice(hp_value_combobox.values[1:])
    ...
```

Also the `command=add_hp_value()` will execute `add_hp_value` immediately.  Use `command=add_hp_value` instead.